# Java: ECC (error correcting code) library?

Tags: java, error-correction

Is there a well-known implementation, that has friendly open-source licensing (not GPL), of an ECC (error correcting code) library (e.g. Reed-Solomon) for Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

Apache License (not sure if that counts in your definition of friendly) I am also not sure if it counts as well known (google knew about it, no 2 result for "java Reed-Solomon")?

Comment: apache license works for me. I've heard of zxing for 2-d bar codes, it's well known, not sure if I want to require the whole jar file for it though.

Comment: you could just use that package the link points to (rip out and rebuild your own jar), the code only imports java.util.Vector so there are no dependencies on the rest of zxing.

Comment: It was written from scratch at Google (by yours truly) since indeed there wasn't much clean, non-GPLed code out there. Reed-Solomon is really a family of algorithms; this implements the variant used in QR Codes and Data Matrix. For your purposes you may have to modify the generator polynomial an points its evaluated at to match your requirements; these vary.

Comment: ah, I was looking at a previous version somehow. That works great -- Justin: thanks for your suggestion. Sean: thanks for implementing! :-)

Comment: Good to hear Jason, and great job Sean :)

Comment: Next time don't use "this" for a link name.. I had to fish the library name out of the url, considering the link itself isn't working. For anyone else looking, it's com.google.zxing.common.reedsolomon in zxing

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Java wrappers for the JErasure Library written by Plank et al. in C.

If you do not mind the native dependency, then JErasure is an excellent choice (if not the best). Until someone ports JErasure to Java, you will have to concise on performance as the implementation in zxing is not that fast when working on larger blocks of data.

I have put the code on GitHub: https://github.com/jvandertil/Jerasure

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student {
    private String ID;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Course> enrolledCourses;

    public Student(String ID, String name, int age) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.enrolledCourses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void enrollCourse(Course course) {
        enrolledCourses.add(course);
    }

    public void viewCourseDetails() {
        System.out.println("Enrolled courses:");
        for (Course course : enrolledCourses) {
            System.out.println(course.getName());
        }
    }

    public void viewGrades() {
        System.out.println("Grades for enrolled courses:");
        for (Course course : enrolledCourses) {
            System.out.println("Course: " + course.getName() + ", Grade: " + course.getGrade(this));
        }
    }
}

class Instructor {
    private String ID;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Course> taughtCourses;

    public Instructor(String ID, String name, int age) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.taughtCourses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void assignCourse(Course course) {
        taughtCourses.add(course);
    }

    public void viewEnrolledStudents(Course course) {
        List<Student> enrolledStudents = course.getEnrolledStudents();
        System.out.println("Enrolled students in " + course.getName() + ":");
        for (Student student : enrolledStudents) {
            System.out.println(student.getName());
        }
    }
}

class Course {
    private String courseCode;
    private String name;
    private Instructor instructor;
    private List<Student> enrolledStudents;
    private Map<Student, Integer> grades;

    public Course(String courseCode, String name, Instructor instructor) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.name = name;
        this.instructor = instructor;
        this.enrolledStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        this.grades = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        enrolledStudents.add(student);
    }

    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }

    public void addGrade(Student student, int grade) {
        grades.put(student, grade);
    }

    public int getGrade(Student student) {
        Integer grade = grades.get(student);
        return (grade != null) ? grade : -1; // Return -1 if grade not found
    }

    public double calculateAverageGrade() {
        int totalGrades = 0;
        for (int grade : grades.values()) {
            totalGrades += grade;
        }
        return (grades.size() > 0) ? (double) totalGrades / grades.size() : 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Student> getEnrolledStudents() {
        return enrolledStudents;
    }
}

class StudentManagementSystem {
    private List<Student> students;
    private List<Instructor> instructors;
    private List<Course> courses;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public StudentManagementSystem() {
        students = new ArrayList<>();
        instructors = new ArrayList<>();
        courses = new ArrayList<>();
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void addStudent() {
        System.out.print("Enter student ID: ");
        String ID = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter student age: ");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        Student student = new Student(ID, name, age);
        students.add(student);
        System.out.println("Student added successfully.");
    }

    public void addInstructor() {
        System.out.print("Enter instructor ID: ");
        String ID = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter instructor name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter instructor age: ");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        Instructor instructor = new Instructor(ID, name, age);
        instructors.add(instructor);
        System.out.println("Instructor added successfully.");
    }

    public void enrollStudentInCourse() {
        System.out.print("Enter student ID: ");
        String studentID = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter course code: ");
        String courseCode = scanner.nextLine();

        Student student = getStudentByID(studentID);
        Course course = getCourseByCode(courseCode);

        if (student != null && course != null) {
            student.enrollCourse(course);
            course.addStudent(student);
            System.out.println("Student enrolled in the course successfully.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid student ID or course code.");
        }
    }

    public void assignInstructorToCourse() {
        System.out.print("Enter instructor ID: ");
        String instructorID = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter course code: ");
        String courseCode = scanner.nextLine();

        Instructor instructor = getInstructorByID(instructorID);
        Course course = getCourseByCode(courseCode);

        if (instructor != null && course != null) {
            instructor.assignCourse(course);
            course.setInstructor(instructor);
            System.out.println("Instructor assigned to the course successfully.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid instructor ID or course code.");
        }
    }

    public void viewCourseDetails() {
        System.out.print("Enter course code: ");
        String courseCode = scanner.nextLine();

        Course course = getCourseByCode(courseCode);

        if (course != null) {
            System.out.println("Course: " + course.getName());
            System.out.println("Instructor: " + course.getInstructor().getName());
            System.out.println("Average Grade: " + course.calculateAverageGrade());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Course not found.");
        }
    }

    public void viewEnrolledStudents() {
        System.out.print("Enter course code: ");
        String courseCode = scanner.nextLine();

        Course course = getCourseByCode(courseCode);

        if (course != null) {
            course.getInstructor().viewEnrolledStudents(course);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Course not found.");
        }
    }

    public Student getStudentByID(String studentID) {
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getID().equals(studentID)) {
                return student;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Instructor getInstructorByID(String instructorID) {
        for (Instructor instructor : instructors) {
            if (instructor.getID().equals(instructorID)) {
                return instructor;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Course getCourseByCode(String courseCode) {
        for (Course course : courses) {
            if (course.getCourseCode().equals(courseCode)) {
                return course;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\n***** Student Management System Menu *****");
            System.out.println("1. Add a new student");
            System.out.println("2. Add a new instructor");
            System.out.println("3. Enroll a student in a course");
            System.out.println("4. Assign an instructor to a course");
            System.out.println("5. View course details and average grades");
            System.out.println("6. View the list of students enrolled in a course");
            System.out.println("0. Exit");

            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    addStudent();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addInstructor();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    enrollStudentInCourse();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    assignInstructorToCourse();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    viewCourseDetails();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    viewEnrolledStudents();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Exiting Student Management System. Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentManagementSystem system = new StudentManagementSystem();
        system.run();
    }
}
```