# library for Multiple-bit Error correcting code?

Tags: java

In my project I want to use Multiple-bit Error correcting Code.I already read about BCH algorithm ,it provide supports for single bit error correction and detection. I also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921599/java-ecc-error-correcting-code-library) 
but it also supports for single bit error correction,so is there  any **library in java** ?

Comment: If you create a `Socket` and communicate through it, you get access to all of the features of TCP (including error correction). I wrote this as a comment instead of an answer, because I understand that you may not want *all* of the overhead of using TCP.

Comment: @john  r u sure it works for multiple bit error correction?

Comment: @swapnil Yes. TCP is a reliable protocol, and `Socket` is Java's implementation of TCP. Therefore, Java sockets are reliable.

Comment: @john then it is good approach to make use of socket for multiple bit error correction , good one.

Comment: @swapnil7 If performance is an issue, TCP may not be the best approach. UDP with a custom algorithm for error correction would be faster.

Comment: @john yes but if packets to be sent are small in size and large in numbers then TCP would be faster than UDP